# React Native declaring arrart inside component keeps throwing Syntax Error

Tags: react-native, syntax-error

I keep getting an SyntaxError from React Native complaining about my array declaration, I don't see an imminent issue, what am I missing? I know it might be something very simple I'm missing but can't see it.

Here's my component:

```js
class More extends Component {

  const items = [
    {
      title: 'Job Board',
      icon: 'home',
      screen: 'JobBoard'
    },
    {
      title: 'Leaderboard',
      icon: 'home',
      screen: 'Leaderboard'
    },
    {
      title: 'Resources',
      icon: 'home',
      screen: 'Resources'
    },
    {
      title: 'Check In',
      icon: 'home',
      screen: 'CheckIn'
    },
    {
      title: 'About',
      icon: 'home',
      screen: 'About'
    }
  ];

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <List>
          {
            items.map((item, i) => {
              <ListItem
                key={i}
                title={item.title}
                leftIcon={{name: item.icon}}
                onPress={() => navigate(item.screen)}
              />
            });
          }
        </List>
      </View>
    );
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});


export { More };
```

[Error from simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA6DK.png)
[Packager feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6CU0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options either you define `const items = [...]` outside the `class` or you may define it in `constructor`and set it to `state`

```
  constructor(){
    super();
    const items = [
      {
        title: 'Job Board',
        icon: 'home',
        screen: 'JobBoard'
      },
      {
        title: 'Leaderboard',
        icon: 'home',
        screen: 'Leaderboard'
      },
      {
        title: 'Resources',
        icon: 'home',
        screen: 'Resources'
      },
      {
        title: 'Check In',
        icon: 'home',
        screen: 'CheckIn'
      },
      {
        title: 'About',
        icon: 'home',
        screen: 'About'
      }
    ];
    this.state = {
      items
    }
  }


render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
        <View style = {styles.container}>
            <List>
                {
                    this.state.items.map((item, i) => {
                        <ListItem
                            key={i}
                            title={item.title}
                            leftIcon={{name: item.icon}}
                            onPress={() => navigate(item.screen)}
                        />
                    });
                }
            </List>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I had tried that before and for some reason it wasn't working I came in with a fresh mind and now it does. Fixed. I am using Redux so just defined it outside the class for now.  Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. Sounds good as the problem is solved! If you found my solution useful, please mark as useful so other users will also find it helpful. Thank you.